# Check if property is bidirectionally bound with other property

Tags: java, javafx, properties

### TL;DR

I've recently worked on a project that has 4 double properties. By nature of the project, the user is allowed to bind these properties either by unidirectional, or bidirectional bindings.

At some point, special care has to be taken if 2 or more of these properties are bound *with each other*, this is true even if it occurs indirectly, where directly means:

```
a.bindBidirectional(b);
```

And indirectly:

```
a.bindBidirectional(x);
x.bindBidirectional(b);
```

The only way I was successful was by setting them one-by-one to some magic number and checking each time if the other properties also changed, but this isn't a very good solution, because it will fire unwanted change events.

My question: Is there any out-of-the-box method for checking whether a property is bound **bidirictionally** with some other specified property?

---

### Detailed Question

I'm currently implementing a `DrawerPane` in JavaFX, that's like this:

[image]

<sup>Shows with the left drawer fully open.</sup>

You can as well set the other 3 sides and control each of them.
The key to nicely control them is by using 4 double properties as deltas where 0.0 is fully closed and 1.0 is fully open.

Additionally, there are 4 `openXxx()` and `closeXxx()` methods that smoothly sets the delta to 1 or 0 respectively using a `Timeline`.

To add flexibility, I designed the properties with public read/write access, so you may bind them (in above image, they are bidirectionally bound to the sliders). Another feature is to bind 2 of them together to open one another if either of them are opened. Think of some Windows 10 apps, when moving mouse to top of screen, the bottom "App Commands" drawer also opens:

[image]

Now, sometimes you want to close all drawers at once (like when clicking the shadow in center, or when losing focus), so I implemented a `closeAll()` method.

First Draft:

```
public void closeAll() {
    closeTop();
    closeLeft();
    closeBottom();
    closeRight();
}
```

After some testing I found that if 2 deltas were bound bidirectionally, calling `closeXxx()` on both, will make the values slightly fluctuating back and forth until finally reaching 0, instead of smoothly decreasing, as 2 `Timelines` compete on setting their values .

Although the user may not notice this, the program sets some CSS pseudoclasses based on the exact value so it may give the wrong result.

My solution:

Second and final Draft:

```
public void closeAll() {

    boolean shouldcloseTop = !topDeltaProperty().isBound(); // unidirection.
    boolean shouldcloseLeft = !leftDeltaProperty().isBound();
    boolean shouldcloseBottom = !bottomDeltaProperty().isBound();
    boolean shouldcloseRight = !rightDeltaProperty().isBound();

    if(shouldCloseTop) {
        setTopDelta(getTopDelta() - 0.01);
        shouldCloseLeft &= getTopDelta() != getLeftDelta();
        shouldCloseBottom &= getTopDelta() != getBottomDelta();
        shouldCloseRight &= getTopDelta() != getRightDelta();
    } if(shouldCloseLeft) {
        setLeftDelta(getLeftDelta() - 0.01);
        shouldCloseBottom &= getLeftDelta() != getBottomDelta();
        shouldCloseRight &= getLeftDelta() != getRightDelta();
    } if(shouldCloseBottom) {
        setBottomDelta(getBottomDelta() - 0.01);
        shouldCloseRight &= getBottomDelta() != getRightDelta();
    }

    if(shouldCloseTop)
        closeTop();
    if(shouldCloseLeft)
        closeLeft();
    if(shouldCloseBottom)
        closeBottom();
    if(shouldCloseRight)
        closeRight();

}
```

Still, is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: AFAIK there's no out-of-the-box functionality for this. You could simply store the state as to which properties are bound to which other properties. Another question though: does your `closeAll()` method create four different timelines? Perhaps you could create a single timeline, and just have a key frame which sets all four key values. I think that would fix the competing calls to set the values.

Comment: @James_D Yes it calls each close method which in turn create their own timelines.

Comment: @James_D How do I "store the states"?

Comment: You can store the states any way you want. E.g. keep a set of pairs of properties which are bidirectionally bound, or for each property keep a set of properties to which it is bidirectionally bound, etc. Then just update those when you bind and unbind. But I would probably try refactoring first so there is only ever one timeline running.

Comment: @James_D But it's the _user_ of my API that binds them, not me!

Comment: Uh, surely you write the code that creates the actual bindings, no?

Comment: @James_D I use `SimpleDoubleProperty`.

Comment: Well, sure: but are you exposing those properties as part of the API? They sound like implementation details. I assumed the properties would be encapsulated within the API and you would expose methods that caused them to be bound. If you expose the properties you have no control over what will be done with them. If you need to do that, implementing a single timeline is probably the better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments:

There is no API (as far as I am aware) for determining if a property is bidirectionally bound to another property.

I would probably recommend not exposing the properties, or at least not exposing them in a writable way in the way you are describing. You could consider exposing an `ObjectProperty<Insets>` that described all four values, and register listeners with it so that it stayed (bidirectionally) synchronized with the actual values of your (now private) properties. You could additionally expose

```
public void bindBidirectional(Side side1, Side side2) ;
```

and

```
public void unbindBidirectional(Side side1, Side side2) ;
```

methods that provided convenient ways to lock the insets on two sides together.

This way you would have complete control over how the values were bound, etc.

Another thing to note is that you describe creating four separate timelines to animate the "sliding". It will work better to create a single timeline and to change which key frames are added to the timeline.

I.e. you could do:

```
// convenience map for looking up appropriate property
private Map<Side, DoubleProperty> propLookup ;

public void close(Side... sides) {

    Timeline t = new Timeline() ;
    Duration d = Duration.seconds(0.5);
    for (Side s : sides) {
        t.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(d, new KeyValue(propLookup.get(s), 0));
    }
    t.play();
}

public void closeAll() {
    close(Side.TOP, Side.RIGHT, Side.BOTTOM, Side.LEFT);
}
```

Here's a sort-of-related demo. There are two rectangles which you can drag around, and a toggle button to bind/unbind their y coordinates bidirectionally.

Drag the blue rectangle down to the bottom of the screen, then bind them, and then send them back to the top.

The current implementation uses a single timeline, and you will see that the y coordinates behave as you would want (i.e. change monotonically in a essentially uniform manner). If you comment out the `sendToTop(rect1, rect2)` and uncomment the lines above it, so you create two timelines together, you will see the kind of behavior you describe, where the y coordinate changes but is slightly modified by the binding.

Demo code:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AnimatingBidirectionallyBoundProperties extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Rectangle rect1 = createDraggableRectangle();
        rect1.setX(50); rect1.setY(50);
        rect1.setFill(Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);


        Rectangle rect2 = createDraggableRectangle();
        rect2.setX(350); rect2.setY(50);
        rect2.setFill(Color.CORAL);

        rect2.yProperty().addListener((obs, oldY, newY) -> System.out.println(oldY + " -> " + newY));

        Pane pane = new Pane(rect1, rect2);

        ToggleButton bind = new ToggleButton("Bind");
        bind.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasBound, isNowBound) -> {
            if (isNowBound) {
                rect2.yProperty().bindBidirectional(rect1.yProperty());
            } else {
                rect2.yProperty().unbindBidirectional(rect1.yProperty());
            }
        });

        Button sendBack = new Button("Send back to top");
        sendBack.setOnAction(e -> {
//          sendToTop(rect1);
//          sendToTop(rect2);
            sendToTop(rect1, rect2);
        });

        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, bind, sendBack);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(pane, null, null, buttons, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void sendToTop(Rectangle... rects) {
        Timeline t = new Timeline();
        for (Rectangle r : rects) {
            t.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), new KeyValue(r.yProperty(), 50)));
        }
        t.play();
    }

    private Rectangle createDraggableRectangle() {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100,50);
        ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseAnchor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        rect.setOnMousePressed(e -> mouseAnchor.set(new Point2D(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY())));
        rect.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            double deltaX = e.getSceneX() - mouseAnchor.get().getX();
            double deltaY = e.getSceneY() - mouseAnchor.get().getY();
            rect.setX(rect.getX() + deltaX);
            rect.setY(rect.getY() + deltaY);
            mouseAnchor.set(new Point2D(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY()));
        });
        return rect ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Output with single timeline:

```
50.0 -> 456.0
456.0 -> 455.86466666666666
455.86466666666666 -> 446.256
446.256 -> 432.58733333333333
432.58733333333333 -> 419.866
419.866 -> 405.656
405.656 -> 391.9873333333333
391.9873333333333 -> 378.86
378.86 -> 365.462
365.462 -> 352.19933333333336
352.19933333333336 -> 338.12466666666666
338.12466666666666 -> 324.86199999999997
324.86199999999997 -> 310.92266666666666
310.92266666666666 -> 297.65999999999997
297.65999999999997 -> 283.856
283.856 -> 270.86400000000003
270.86400000000003 -> 256.92466666666667
256.92466666666667 -> 243.39133333333336
243.39133333333336 -> 229.72266666666667
229.72266666666667 -> 216.73066666666665
216.73066666666665 -> 202.656
202.656 -> 188.98733333333337
188.98733333333337 -> 175.72466666666668
175.72466666666668 -> 162.32666666666665
162.32666666666665 -> 148.7933333333333
148.7933333333333 -> 134.98933333333332
134.98933333333332 -> 121.32066666666668
121.32066666666668 -> 108.32866666666666
108.32866666666666 -> 94.65999999999997
94.65999999999997 -> 80.72066666666666
80.72066666666666 -> 67.45800000000003
67.45800000000003 -> 53.51866666666666
53.51866666666666 -> 50.0
```

Output with two timelines:

```
50.0 -> 444.0
444.0 -> 443.7373333333333
443.7373333333333 -> 443.8686666666667
443.8686666666667 -> 434.28133333333335
434.28133333333335 -> 434.41266666666667
434.41266666666667 -> 420.36
420.36 -> 420.49133333333333
420.49133333333333 -> 407.358
407.358 -> 407.4893333333333
407.4893333333333 -> 394.0933333333333
394.0933333333333 -> 394.2246666666667
394.2246666666667 -> 381.09133333333335
381.09133333333335 -> 381.22266666666667
381.22266666666667 -> 367.95799999999997
367.95799999999997 -> 368.08933333333334
368.08933333333334 -> 354.562
354.562 -> 354.6933333333333
354.6933333333333 -> 341.56
341.56 -> 341.6913333333333
341.6913333333333 -> 328.558
328.558 -> 328.6893333333333
328.6893333333333 -> 315.42466666666667
315.42466666666667 -> 315.556
315.556 -> 302.29133333333334
302.29133333333334 -> 302.42266666666666
302.42266666666666 -> 289.28933333333333
289.28933333333333 -> 289.42066666666665
289.42066666666665 -> 275.8933333333333
275.8933333333333 -> 276.0246666666667
276.0246666666667 -> 263.28533333333337
263.28533333333337 -> 263.4166666666667
263.4166666666667 -> 249.88933333333335
249.88933333333335 -> 250.02066666666667
250.02066666666667 -> 236.88733333333334
236.88733333333334 -> 237.01866666666666
237.01866666666666 -> 224.01666666666665
224.01666666666665 -> 224.14799999999997
224.14799999999997 -> 210.358
210.358 -> 210.48933333333332
210.48933333333332 -> 197.22466666666668
197.22466666666668 -> 197.356
197.356 -> 184.09133333333335
184.09133333333335 -> 184.22266666666667
184.22266666666667 -> 170.95800000000003
170.95800000000003 -> 171.08933333333334
171.08933333333334 -> 157.82466666666664
157.82466666666664 -> 157.95600000000002
157.95600000000002 -> 145.08533333333332
145.08533333333332 -> 145.2166666666667
145.2166666666667 -> 131.558
131.558 -> 131.68933333333337
131.68933333333337 -> 118.68733333333336
118.68733333333336 -> 118.81866666666667
118.81866666666667 -> 104.89733333333334
104.89733333333334 -> 105.02866666666671
105.02866666666671 -> 92.15800000000002
92.15800000000002 -> 92.28933333333333
92.28933333333333 -> 78.762
78.762 -> 78.89333333333332
78.89333333333332 -> 66.154
66.154 -> 66.28533333333331
66.28533333333331 -> 52.75799999999998
52.75799999999998 -> 52.8893333333333
52.8893333333333 -> 50.0
```

Comment: Was away from this project for a while, sorry for delayed acception.